# for loop statement always true

Tags: java, for-loop, swingworker

Long story short I am trying to create port sniffer with very simple gui.
Without the worker, port sniffer is working fine, but i wanted to update area1 every time it finds open port. After adding worker, "for" loop does not loop. So it would be nice if someone could show me where the problem is.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

// definējam galveno klasi
public class PortScanner extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton poga1 = new JButton("palaist skaneri");
JTextField jt = new JTextField ("ievadam adresi",30);
SwingWorker worker;
JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea(5, 40);
//taisam konsturkoturu
public PortScanner(){
    //virsraksts
    super("Portu skaneris007");
    //definejam konteineru
    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //liekam konteineri izkartojumu
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //ieliekam logā pogu
    content.add(poga1);
    content.add(jt);
    content.add(area1);
         //ramim izmeri
    setSize(600,500);
    //pieliekam klausitaju
    poga1.addActionListener(this);
    jt.addActionListener(this);

    //aiversanas operacija
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    if(a.getSource()== poga1){
        //seit bus darbiba ko veiks poga
        this.metode1();

    }

 }

public void metode1() {
    area1.setText("");
    if (worker != null) {
        worker.cancel(false);
    }
    worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() {

            for (int port = 1; port <= 65535; port++) {  //65535
                try {

                    String input = jt.getText();
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(input, port), 1000);
                    socket.close();
                    area1.append("ports " + port + "atvērts \n");
                    System.out.println("Port " + port + " is open");
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
                return 0;
            }
            worker.execute();
            return null;
        }

    };
}

public static void main(String []args) {
    new PortScanner();
}
}
```

Comment: You put `return 0` at the end of your `for` loop, so when it reaches that point it will of course return from the `doInBackground` function, which means that the rest of the loop will not run.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
return 0;
```

will always return from the method and therefore terminate the loop, no matter what the actual value for `port`. The code will only execute once.